# Get property value from an object inside of an array

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to grab class `code` property **value** from the object inside each array belonging to "class". (I'm aware my data is convoluted).

This is my student array:

```
student = [
     {"class":[{
          "code":"PSJ001",
          "professor":"McHale",
          "description":"course description"}]
     },
     {"class":[{
          "code":"ENG303",
          "professor":"Dench",
          "description":"course description"}]
      },
     {"class":[{
          "code":"SCI003",
          "professor":"Biju",
          "description":"course description"}]
     }
]
```

What I'm trying to get is...

```
['PSJ001','ENG303','SCI003']
```

This is what I have...

```
let classCodes = [];
for (const i in student) {
   classCodes = classCodes.concat(student[i].map(obj => {
       return obj.code;
   }));
}
```

What am I doing wrong here? (written in jsx)

Comment: Your dev console should tell you that `students` doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to get desired result

```js
var student = [{"class":[{"code":"PSJ001","professor":"McHale","description":"course description"}]},{"class":[{"code":"ENG303","professor":"Dench","description":"course description"}]},{"class":[{"code":"SCI003","professor":"Biju","description":"course description"}]}];

var result = student.map(function(e) {
  return e.class[0].code;
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically this will work reliable:

```
student.map(o => o.class.map(c => c.code)).reduce((obj, arr) => arr.push(...obj) && arr, []);
```

First we use `.map()` to get the classes, and inside we use `.map()` again to get the codes. This gives us a array of arrays. Then we use `.reduce()` to flatten that array.